# Nested ngFor to create multiple select

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hello I'm new with angular and ionic 3
I've been trying to figure out how to do a nested `ngFor` to create a select option based on my records in the database.

I'm using REST API to connect to a PHP page that connects to my mySQL Database.

The record I wanted to use are as follows:

```
Table 1 (Group)

ID    |    Item ID    |    Description

1 | 1 | Type of bun

2 | 1 | Toppings

3 | 2 | Size

Table 2 (Options)   

ID |    group_id |  Description

1 | 1 | Regular

2 | 1 | Whole Wheat

3 | 1 | Sesame

4 | 2 | Cheese

5 | 2 | Tomato

6 | 3 | Large

7 | 3 | Medium

8 | 3 | Regular

Now i wanted to create a select dropdown like this:

For ITEM ID 1:

Type of Bun

---- Regular

---- Whole Wheat

---- Sesame

Toppings

---- Cheese

---- Tomato

For ITEM ID 2:

Size

---- Large

---- Medium

---- Regular
```

I've been trying to do something like:

```
<ion-item class="item-leave-height" *ngFor="let rec of group">
  <ion-label>{{rec.ID}}</ion-label>
  {{getOptions(rec.ID)}} //<-- Call function that gets the records from rest
  <ion-select interface="action-sheet">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let option of itemOptions;" value="{{ option.ID }}">{{ option.description }}</ion-option>
   </ion-select>
```

`getOptions` method there will call the service that connects to the REST Api. I know its dirty and I don't like it but I've been trying to figure this out almost the whole day :(

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: you should invoke your "getOptions" method in the onInit or constructor. The idea is that all data should be available when you start rendering your ngFor template. In your case, there will be no data in itemOptions when the nested ngFor runs as it is still being fetched

Comment: Please clarify it .... Its two select box or not?? second select box depens on first one ...

Comment: don't use functions in bindings. your function will be called on every change detection cycle, and angular runs x2 cycles in dev mode.

Comment: yes its multiple select but no its not dependent on the selection of the first select. but the select boxes are group by item id which is passed by the navparams from the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

you should invoke your `getOptions` method in the onInit or constructor. The idea is that all data should be available when you start rendering your ngFor template. In your case, there will be no data in `itemOptions` when the nested ngFor runs as it is still being fetched. Something like:

```
ngOnInit(){
    //where group is a collection of data items you want to iterate on
    this.group.forEach((rec)=>{
         this.getOptions(rec.ID).then((options)=>{
              rec.options = options;
         })
    })
}
```

Update:

A possible template can look like this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let rec of group">
    <ion-label>{{rec.id}}</ion-label>
    <ion-select interface="action-sheet">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let option of rec.options" [value]="option.id">{{ option.description }}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Assuming that after `ngOnInit` the data looks something like:

```
group = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "Type Of Bun"
        options: [{"id":1, "description":"Regular"}]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Himashu but how can i use this to display the select boxes in my html?